# Passing char arrays to a function

Tags: c

The dreaded `warning: passing argument 1 of ... makes integer from pointer without a cast`

I just don't understand this. All I am trying to do is to pass a simple string (yes, I know a character array) to a function. The function parses the string and returns the first part. Can somebody please show me what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

```
char* get_request_type(char* buffer) {
    char* p;
    p = strtok(buffer, "|");
    return p;
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[30] = "test|something";
    fprintf(stdout, "buffer: %s\n", buffer);  //<-- looks great but needs parsing
    char* request_type = get_request_type(buffer);  //<-- error is here
    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", request_type); //<--expecting to see 'test'

}
```

There may yet come a day when I get comfortable working with strings in C, but that day is not this day...

Comment: is that the ACTUAL code?

Comment: The relevant parts of it.

Comment: Is get_request_type() defined above main?

Comment: that function is in a separate .c file. It's fully included, compiled, and works just fine. The error is coming from main and I don't think has anything to do with the function itself - at least as far as I can see. I may certainly be passing the argument incorrectly, however.

Comment: turn on all warnings and ensure it builds cleanly under C99.  Looks like an implicit function definition.

Comment: Post the shortest, complete compilable example that you can which exhibits this error.

Comment: When the compiler parses main, it needs to know how get_request_type() is defined. So either you need a prototype declaration or you need to be sure get_request_type() is parsed before main. But even this doesn't really explain the warning message.

Comment: Very sorry, everybody. It seems that I didn't explain this very clearly. I edited it, so it should be more clear, I hope. I think that this is one of those rookie C programmer mistakes that confuses people  like me who only work in C when mandatory. Let me know if it is still confusing. Sorry again.

Comment: @Charlie: It actually does explain the warning. In early C (and possibly still today), attempting to call a function that is not yet visible to the compiler results in the compiler assuming that the return type and parameter types are all `int`.

Comment: @usr5410 Is that _exactly_ what you are building when you get this error? For example, this error could definitely occur if the functions were in the other order (e.g. main on top).

Comment: @Charlie - you're right. In my .h file, I had `char* get_request_type(char buffer)` I forgot the `*` in the parameter. Unbelievable. Big thanks to everybody. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: All of this could have been avoided if you had posted a compilable question. No problem, but next time...

Comment: Not to mention that preparing a compilable example to post would almost certainly have solved the issue before the question was asked.

Comment: All true. However, it's rather hard to post a compilable example when the very problem that I am having is that I can't get it to compile in  the first place! In my defense, when I have no confidence in my ability to manipulate C strings, my supposition is that I must be doing something wrong with the pointers, particularly when the error mentions a problem casting pointers. In this case, it was elsewhere, but I didn't realize that.

Comment: @usr55410, first of all don't feel bad (really).  Approach problems like this in increments.  you didn't need to call the routine, as : `char *request_type = strtok(buffer, "|");` would be sufficient.  Once you get this code to work, then add the call to the sub-routine.  FYI, we all take baby steps all the time, but just don't admit it!

Comment: Just a blind guess, did you add "string.h" header file ?

Comment: @usr55410 Errors like this can't happen if you include the .h file in both .c files.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't include `string.h`, so the compiler will assume that `strtok` is defined as:

```
int strtok();
```

returns `int` and takes unknown number of arguments, it's call *implicit function declaration*. The solution is just to include `string.h` where `strtok` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of the code works well. Post if there is still any problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* get_request_type(char *buffer) {
        char *p; 
        printf("----%s\n",buffer);
        p = strtok(buffer, "|");
        //fprintf("%s--->",p);  
        return p;
}

int main()
{
        char buffer[30] = "test|something";
        fprintf(stdout, "buffer: %s\n", buffer);  //<-- looks great but needs parsing
        char* request_type = get_request_type(buffer);  //<-- No error here
        fprintf(stdout, "request_type: %s\n", request_type);
        return 0;
}
```